# jQuery on click slide toggle works in mobile, but breaks when brought back to desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my html and jquery code. It works great on mobile, but when brought back to desktop breaks the navbar. Any ideas? I'm using bulma.io

HTML

```
 <span class="nav-toggle">
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
  <span></span>
 </span>

  <!-- This "nav-menu" is hidden on mobile -->
  <!-- Add the modifier "is-active" to display it on mobile -->
  <div class="nav-right nav-menu">
    <a class="nav-item">
      Home
    </a>
    <a class="nav-item">
      Documentation
    </a>
    <a class="nav-item">
      Blog
    </a>
```

Javasciprt

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-toggle").click(function(){
        $(".nav-menu").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px), print {
   .nav-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? Or used any other responsive media queries?

Comment: @RohanKumar I'm using bulma.io

Answer (score 2):

If you hide the menu at mobile using slide toggle, what happens is the jQuery is adding a display:none inline on the nav menu.

A quick and dirty fix would be a CSS change:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px), print {
   .nav-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-menu { display:block !important; }
}
```

You could also do a more involved fix, which would be changing the class of the nav-menu on click and using css for the animation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-toggle").click(function(){
        var navMenu = $(".nav-menu");

        if(navMenu.hasClass('open')){
            navMenu.removeClass('open');
        } else {
            navMenu.addClass('open');
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.nav-menu { max-height:0; opacity:0; transition:all .3s; }
.nav-memu.open { max-height:80em; opacity:1; }

@media(min-width:769px){
    .nav-menu { max-height:none; opacity:1; }
}
```

Issue with this approach is you might need to adjust max height depending on how long a menu can get.

[Here's a fiddle](https://codepen.io/stufu/pen/mwqNdV)

Answer (score 2):

Reset your script on resize this will fix your issue

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".nav-menu").removeAttr("style");
});
```